# Command SetPrefix and Json? Discord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

First:
I wanted to add more functions to my bot so that I created a new folder where I would try new things!

Second:
I wanted to add a command to set a prefix!

Third:
I added a prefix.json file and a start.bat to start the bot next to the bot.py

Fourth:
TROUBLE!
When writing the script with more than 1280 likes, the bat and the python file did not load, they both closed

Fifth:
The script!

```
import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands

def get_prefix(bot, message):
    with open('prefix.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    return prefixes[str(guild.id)] = '.'

token = 'Private (-:'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='c:', help_command=None)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Ya estoy')

@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('prefix.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = '.'

    with open('prefix.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

@bot.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    with open('prefix.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))

    with open('prefix.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

@bot.command()
async def setprefix(ctx, prefix):
    with open('prefix.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix

    with open('prefix.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score 1):

First: What's the problem there?

Second: your `get_prefix` function needs to be passed into the command_prefix of `Bot`

code:

```py
def get_prefix(bot, message): 
    with open('prefix.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, help_command=None)
```

Third: what's the issue with your bat file?

fourth: I'm not sure what your bat is doing and what you're doing with it.

Comment: Hi, no error!
It only closes the python console and the bat if I open either, as if it didn't work!
I do not define the problem well since there is no error code only the consoles are closed seconds after opening!
Another thing is that with the official script of my bot nothing happens, it works quite well!
I use the bat because the script of my official bot does not open correctly but the bat executes everything correctly!

Comment: I already tried to do the second thing you put in and it doesn't work either!

Comment: I just realized you're overwriting the prefix for the guild while returning None. `return prefixes[str(guild.id)] = '.'` should be just `return prefixes[str(guild.id)]` you should probably also add a default prefix somewhere